# What is the difference between $\gg$ and $\gt$?

Tags: notation

What is the difference between $\gg$ and $\gt$ ?

Thank you $\infty$ times.

Comment: The difference is whether or not the left-hand-side is $\infty$ times greater than the right-hand-side. $\:$ ^_^ $\;\;\;$

Comment: of $>>$ means significantly larger than

Comment: a >> b means that a is much much larger than b; a > b would just mean that a is larger than b [1.00001 > 1 but 100001 >> 1]

Comment: $a \gt b$ means $a$ is greater than $b$ so for example $1.0001 \gt 1$. While  $a \gg b$ means $a$ is much larger than $b$.  We would not say $1.0001 \gg 1$ but may say $100000 \gg 1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This is hardly mathematics.

Comment: @WarrenHill Sorry but I would **never** say $100000\gg1$.

Comment: @Did: as measures on a singleton, $100000 \gg 1$

Comment: @Did. I agree with you but for illustration puroposes with numbers of "human" sizes ... ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Only confuses things.

Answer (score 1):

Imprecisely, we usually say that $a\gg b$ means that $a$ is *much larger* than $b$.  Of course, this seems like it depends a great deal on how you define "much".

I usually only see this notation used in asymptotics: that is, we take $a\gg b$ to mean the same thing as $b=o(a)$, which means that $a=a(n)$ and $b=b(n)$ depend on some $n$, and
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b(n)}{a(n)}=0.
$$